# robocopy not retrying failed files

Tags: windows, robocopy, floppy

I'm currently trying to fetch old files off of a box of floppy disks and many of the files fail on the first try but copy successfully after a few tries, I'm assuming because the internal cleaning mechanism is doing its job or something.

I'm using robocopy to copy the files, but no matter what I set the /r: flag to, it only tries once. I've used robocopy in the past to read files off damaged optical media and skip the errors after only a couple of tries, but that was a while ago.

Comment: Did you find the culprit for this? I have same problem on Windows 2019 Server.

Comment: I did not, I ended up writing a quick script to run robocopy multiple times instead

Comment: It seems this is a widespread issue in Windows 10/Server 2019: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/144678/robocopy-doesn39t-retry-on-open-files-any-more.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the /n: flag to specify the number of retries. If you set /n:3, robocopy will try to copy the file three times then give up.